# Background image not working javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Newbie to javafx, and i am currently unable to get my image to become my background, its probably something silly. Here's the code. Any help appreciated.

```
package game;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
public class appgame extends Application {

    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title of the Window");
        Pane p = new HBox();
        p.setPadding(new javafx.geometry.Insets(5,5,5,5));
        Image image = new Image("file:/home/rex/Documents/codes/java/bg1.jpg");

BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(image,BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

Background background = new Background(backgroundImage);

        Scene scene = new Scene(p, 306, 460);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am unable to connect my background to my scene, please some one help me set my image as my scene background. Currently the code only shows a blank stage, without the background image. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the background to the instantiated Pane (p).

```
package appgame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition.CENTER;
import static javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT;
import static javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT;
import static javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize.*;

public class AppGame extends Application {

    private static final String BACKGROUND_PATH = "<path to background>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane p = new HBox();
        p.setPadding(new javafx.geometry.Insets(5,5,5,5));
        //Set your background!
        p.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(new Image(BACKGROUND_PATH), REPEAT, NO_REPEAT, CENTER, DEFAULT)));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Title of the Window");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(p, 306, 460));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This results in (using a png on my filesystem):

[image]

Comment: thanks @skubski
I would really appreciate if you could also give me some resources for learning javafx, every resource i have kind of stinks.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I've read the [getting started](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm), and I've read [Mastering-JavaFX](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-JavaFX-Controls-Oracle-Press/dp/0071833773/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_img_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=WEYJ9N4TBTRB4VRJR68N) from Oracle. But it's practice that makes perfect. ;)

Comment: What i am trying to do is make a game, called parachute panic, or a playable version of it. Does the oracle documentation have Animation part of JavaFX. Sorry for all these questions.
And Thank you.

Comment: The getting started guide has a small introduction on visual aspects. They explain you how to render basic objects as rectangles and such on panes. This should get you started on how to draw objects on panes. I have no specific game design guide though. If this answer has solved your problem please accept so. Good luck with your project.